# Analytical solution to a second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hey all here is my equation in a 2D system.

$$\nabla^2u(x,y) = -\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$

I haven't done anything like this in a while so could use a bit of guidance, how do I go about solving this to obtain a value of $u$ depending on $x$ and $y$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $\nabla^2u(x,y) =0$ is on the form $u(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$ where $f$ and $g$ are any functions at least two times derivable.

Obviously, a particular solution of $\nabla^2u(x,y) = -\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$

To check it, differentiate two times and bring it back into the PDE.

So, the general solution of $\nabla^2u(x,y) = -\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$ is :
$$u(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)+\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$$